# Where to store data to follow MVC pattern

Tags: objective-c, macos, model-view-controller, model

I finally managed to finish my first little osx app and I'm so proud of myself! But I'm still confused with the obj-c MVC approach I really try to follow. Reading all the different tutorials does't give me the final clue.
I use Hillegass book "cocoa programming for MAC OS X". The following pattern is used to bind user inputs with an `tableview` via `NSArrayController` in my controller-class:

```
- (IBAction)pushAdd:(id)sender {

    ToDoItem *newToDo = [[ToDoItem alloc] init];

    [newToDo setValue:[_inputName stringValue] forKey:@"name"];
    [newToDo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_inputNomValue doubleValue]] forKey:@"nomValue"];
    [newToDo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_inputTolerancePlus doubleValue]] forKey:@"tolerancePlus"];
    [newToDo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[_inputToleranceMinus doubleValue]] forKey:@"toleranceMinus"];
    [newToDo setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_inputDistribution titleOfSelectedItem]] forKey:@"distribution"];
    [newToDo setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_inputDirection titleOfSelectedItem]] forKey:@"direction"];

    [toDoItemArrayController addObject:newToDo];

...
```

MY QUESTION:

Since my model-class `ToDoItem` is used as a blueprint to create the `ToDoItem` entities the complete information is stored within the `toDoItemArrayController` controller (not in the model).
But what if I need to use the array information somewhere else? Do I need to define an additional array in my `ToDoItem` model-class with all the information from the `toDoItemArrayController`? My MVC understanding so far is that the model should contain all the information which is later handled by controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass around the array with objects of `ToDoItem` between the contollers. But declaring an array inside `ToDoItem` which is not related to your data model would not be according to the MVC pattern.
For accessing the array somewhere else you could pass it around , for example maybe using a singleton or commonly accessible object like the AppDelegate.

Comment: Rakesh, thanks for the answer. Why would the array with all the ToDoItems not be related to the ToDoItem model data model in my case?

Comment: Well it's not part of the data model. Its just the collection of your objects created from the data model.

Comment: Think of this, if you had an array declared inside ToDoItem for storing all the objects of ToDoItem, all your objects created will have an array in turn stores all the objects created. And all the objects inside this array will have the same array and so on. Make sense?

Comment: Rakesh, thanks. It makes sense. Is there a source with sample code showing the MVC concept and how a model class could look like you would know of?

Comment: Right now don't have one. But you'll find many on googling. Let me try .